# Grails - Spring Security and LDAP mapping to database

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I am validating the users of my application with LDAP, and it works. 
But now I need to assign my own roles and map them to my database.
I have been following a few tutorials, like this: https://chlebik.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/ldap-authentication-and-db-authorisation-with-grails-spring-security/

My problem is that my imports have errors because Grails doesn´t found the classes. For example:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
```

I am using Grails 2.4.4
My plugins in config.groovy:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
```

If you need any information, tell to me please.
Any help or tutorial would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Those would be

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
```

The source is [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core) and the docs include a section on [changes made in the 2.0 plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV2.html).

Comment: I have changed the first one and it works. But not with the others. 
I read your link, and I saw that the packages has changed.
However, I can´t find the right packages of all my imports. Do you know any other place where I can find it?

Comment: The Spring Security javadoc is [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/)